# Having every argument of an annotation on a different line on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting, ide

I am trying to have every argument of an annotation on a different line on eclipse. Currently I have this:

```
@Table(name = "student", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(name = "student_email_unique", columnNames = "email")
})
```

what I would like to have is this:

```
@Table(
    name = "student", 
    uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(
            name = "student_email_unique", 
            columnNames = "email"
        )
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

- For formatting the **`args` inside `{}`** 
  **-->** In the **`Array initializers`** > set how you want to `split`

  - (though, this *messy* up your `normal Arrays` ...)
  - (you may try set `After opening brace of array initializer` too)
- For formatting the **`args` inside `()`** 
  You need to **manually** place **linebreak** in the `arg` inside the `()`, then Eclipse will **preserve** the linebreak (, and may?< reformat the other args)

  - (not sure where exactly the settings locate, if exist).
- (*some other settings may help too, idk*)
- *setting graph
  [image: setting graph]

Answer (score -1):

Prevent formatting as follows

```
// @formatter:off
@Table(
    name = "student", 
    uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(
            name = "student_email_unique", 
            columnNames = "email"
        )
    }
)
// @formatter:on
```

Comment: the thing is that I would like the formatter to do it automatically

Comment: I don't actively use Eclipse, but I believe in the formatter you may be able to specify new lines after annotations